# TornadoWeb Python

Tags: python

I'm currently working with TornadoWeb but appear to have picked up a lot of bad habbits. I'd appreciate some feedback on the code below:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.template

#modules
import auth
import base
import tag

#pymongo
import pymongo
connection = pymongo.Connection("127.0.0.1", 27017)
db = connection.prod
loader = tornado.template.Loader("templates")
class CustomerJS(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        ckey = self.get_secure_cookie('ckey')
        self.set_header("Content-Type", "Application/x-javascript")
        self.write(loader.load('js/customer.js').generate(ckey=ckey))


class Account(base.Base):
    def get(self):
        self.render('account.html', None)

class Sites(base.Base):
    def get(self):
        self.render('sites.html', None)

class Ads(base.Base):
    def get(self):
        self.render('ads.html', None)

application = tornado.web.Application([
        ## MAIN TABS
        # home
        (r"/version/3/home", Account),
        # ads
        (r"/version/3/ads", Ads),
        (r"/version/3/tags", tag.Tags),
        (r"/version/3/tagPost", tag.tagPost),
        (r"/version/3/tagRemove", tag.tagRemove),
        (r"/version/3/tagReportCookies", tag.tagReportCookies),
            (r"/version/3/s/(.*)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {"path": "static"}),
            # JAVASCRIPT
            (r"/version/3/customer.js", CustomerJS),
            ], cookie_secret="COOKIESECRET=")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(9099)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.template

#modules
```

This comment doesn't say much, its fairly clear that anything starting with `import` is a module. It would be better to say something about why these three modules are grouped - eg, 'http/html modules'. But for a low number of imports, you mightn't bother with the comment at all.

```
import auth
import base
import tag

#pymongo
```

Same again; this comment doesn't say anything that the code doesn't. This one you can just drop.

```
import pymongo
```

Put a blank line below your last `import`. Also, where are `auth`, `tag` and `base` from? They sound like your own support modules rather than part of a third-party package, in which case the imports should go *after* pymongo, rather than before, per PEP 8.

```
connection = pymongo.Connection("127.0.0.1", 27017)
db = connection.prod
loader = tornado.template.Loader("templates")
class CustomerJS(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        ckey = self.get_secure_cookie('ckey')
```

Stick to either single or double quotes throughout your code, rather than swapping between them.

```
        self.set_header("Content-Type", "Application/x-javascript")
        self.write(loader.load('js/customer.js').generate(ckey=ckey))


class Account(base.Base):
```

If `base` is your own module, you should pick a better name for it.

```
    def get(self):
        self.render('account.html', None)

class Sites(base.Base):
    def get(self):
        self.render('sites.html', None)

class Ads(base.Base):
    def get(self):
        self.render('ads.html', None)
```

These three classes differ only by one hard-coded string argument. I'm assuming these are going to be expanded a bit later, but even so - consider consolidating them.

```
application = tornado.web.Application([
        ## MAIN TABS
        # home
```

Drop this comment, its clear that its the home page from the next line.

```
        (r"/version/3/home", Account),
```

Is there a reason why all of these strings are raw strings?

```
        # ads
```

Does this comment really apply to the entire next block of code (including the bits dealing with `Tags` and `tagPost`, etc)? If it doesn't, the comment is not only redundant but actually *misleading*.

```
        (r"/version/3/ads", Ads),
        (r"/version/3/tags", tag.Tags),
        (r"/version/3/tagPost", tag.tagPost),
        (r"/version/3/tagRemove", tag.tagRemove),
        (r"/version/3/tagReportCookies", tag.tagReportCookies),
            (r"/version/3/s/(.*)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {"path": "static"}),
```

Why do you suddenly indent further from here?

```
        # JAVASCRIPT
```

Put a blank line before this.

```
        (r"/version/3/customer.js", CustomerJS),
        ], cookie_secret="COOKIESECRET=")
```

You've passed a long list as the first argument to `Application`, and then a single string value as a second - but the way you've set it out, it could be mistaken as sending many arguments to `Application`. Better to do it this way:

```
Application(
     [ # Main tabs
       (r"/version/3/home", Account),
       (r"/version/3/ads", Ads),
            ...
      # Javascript
       (r"/version/3/customer.js", CustomerJS),
      ],
      cookie_secret="COOKIESECRET="
)
```

Or something similar, to make it obvious what your code is actually doing.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(9099)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```